# How to check if =importxml elements don't exist in google spreadsheet then insert those elements to sheet?

Tags: xpath, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i am using this code to pull google search result using =importxml formula.Column A and B is for result of importXML.
Column c is for url of goole search query and column D and E holds //h3[@class='r'] and //h3/a/@href.

Currently the code keeps overwriting the old data if i call the function multiple times. 
What i want to check if xml elements dont exist in entire sheet then insert them to sheet?Is there away to acomplish this ?

Note:google search result returns 10 sets of data when it is called

```
function getData() {
  var queryString = Math.random();

  var cellFunction1 = '=IMPORTXML("' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C2').getValue() + '&randomNumber=' + queryString + '","'+ SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D2').getValue() + '")';
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2').setValue(cellFunction1);

  var cellFunction2 = '=IMPORTXML("' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C2').getValue() + '&randomNumber=' + queryString + '","'+ SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E2').getValue() + '")';
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B2').setValue(cellFunction2);
}
```

Comment: what are you using to compare the content of the xml, and iterate its data to be able to look if it exists in the sheet?